# How many ways nine people can sit on these chairs if at least one of the chairs in row two must remain unoccupied?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

[image: the rows of chairs picture]

Question: find how many ways nine people can sit on these chairs if at least one of the chairs in row two must remain unoccupied.

Attempt: $9!+(9!)(10C9)(6)+(9!)(11C9)(3)=82010880$

Reasoning: if three chairs are unoccupied, then there are $9!$ ways, if two chairs are unoccupied, there are $(9!)(10C9)(6)$ {the $6$ because the possible ways the unoccupied chairs are arranged}, $(9!)(11C9)(3)$ if one chair is $(9!)(11C9)(3)$

Correct answer: $59512320$

Could someone please help me understand what I am doing incorrectly?

Comment: The diagram is confusing, and makes the question ambiguous: what does _row_ mean here? The chairs appear to be facing left, so a row in a classroom, say, would contain three chairs. But it seems that the question is intending that a row contains four chairs. At least, that is what JMP's answer assumes, and it arrives at the correct answer. The use of "row two" also suggests this interpretation. (By the way, there are only $3$ possible ways to arrange two unoccupied chairs in a row of three, not $6$.)

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively, you can use complimentary method.

Number of total arrangements $ = \displaystyle {12 \choose 9} \cdot 9! = 79833600$

Number of arrangements in which all four seats of the second row are occupied $ = \displaystyle {9 \choose 4} \cdot 4! \cdot {8 \choose 5} \cdot 5! = 20321280$

(You choose four people out of nine and arrange them in second row. Then you arrange the remaining people in eight seats from the first and third rows)

So number of arrangements where at least one of the seats in the second row is not occupied
$$ = 79833600 - 20321280 = 59512320$$

Comment: The is an alternative way to do it with the same concept (complimentary method): 12P9-(9C4*4!*8P5)=59512320

Comment: @123321123321 $nPm = \binom{n}{m} \cdot m!$

Answer (score 2):

I take it that there are four chairs in each "row"

You can apply inclusion-exclusion to avoid double counting viz

$C(4,1)*P(11,9) -C(4,2)*P(10,9) + C(4,3)*P(9,9) = 59512320$

**Another way**

P(row $2$ not full)$\times$(All permutations)

$=\left(1- \frac9{12}\frac 8{11}\frac7{10}\frac69 \right)\times P(12,9) =\frac{41}{55}\times P(12,9) = 59512320$

Comment: The question asks us to find how many ways nine can sit on the $12$ chairs so that at least one chair in row 2 must remain unoccupied.  While you solution is valid, the way you described your first term makes it sound like that term is the answer to the question.  What you are actually doing is selecting $k$ chairs in row 2 to be empty and seating people in the remaining chairs.

Comment: @N.F. Taussig: Right, I've removed the wording.

Answer (score 1):

It is a matter of arranging the unoccupied chairs for each case. First, line up the $9$ people in any of the $9!$ ways.

If there is only one occupied chair in row $2$, then there are $4$ ways to position it.

If there are $2$ occupied chairs, then there is $1$ space in either row $1$ or row $3$, and $6$ ways in row $2$.

If there are $3$ occupied chairs, there are $\binom{8}{2}=28$ ways for the spaces in rows $1$ and $3$, and $4$ in row $2$.

So the final answer is $9!(4+8\cdot6+28\cdot4)=59,512,320$.